# get php error, warning, notice and alert them with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, error-handling

Well the title says it all. I want to get any php error, warning, notice and alert them via JavaScript in my own format. Is that possible? If yes then how? I have tried this but it won't catch warnings or notices i guess.

```
try{
    $result = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    oci_execute($result);
}catch(Exception  $e){
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";  
    ///////////or anything to alert with JavaScript///////////
}
```

Comment: Yes and yes to your question. The **how**  will depend on what you have tried. As of now you have not showed what you have tried and what is not working.

Comment: my bad, well I have tried a very simple code, i'm editing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code :

```
<?php
try{
$result = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($result);
}
catch(Exception  $e){
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Caught exception")';  
echo '</script>';
}
?>
```

**Updated based on your comment**

```
<?php
session_start();

//set this in your catch block
$_SESSION['flash'] = 'message'; 

//check for it in everypage.
if(isset($_SESSION['flash']) && !empty($_SESSION['flash']))
{
   echo '<div id="flash_container">'.$_SESSION['flash'].'</div>';
   unset($_SESSION['flash']);
}
?>
```

Or try this

http://mikeeverhart.net/php-flash-messages/

Comment: Thanks but actually I need to specify the exact exception in the alert box. Say a user just gave an input in the database but forgot to give the id. So then oracle will throw an exception saying  
  
    'ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into  .... '
  
I want to show it in a well readable format so that the user can understand what he has done wrong. Besides php will treat it as a warning because the problem occurred in oracle not in php. So I want to catch any error, warning, notice in a variable and display it through an alert box.

Comment: @WahidMasud hope this link will be usefull for you     http://toddnestor.com/rails-like-flash-messages-in-php/

Comment: @ Preethi Mano.. Lot of thanks to you. Well I couldn't find what I wanted from those links you provided but so what I got the idea from there and solved the problem :) I'm posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just used JavaScript and got the error text. For those who have faced similar problem:

```
$('.xdebug-error').find("th:first").text();
```

It will get the error text. If its a warning then just changing the class to 'xe-warning' would do the work! Now its possible to format the text and alert it as the user requires.